# How to zoom in part of the plot and remove annotation outside the zoomed area?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I've created a plot with`geom_rect` and added the annotation with `geom_text_repel` but when I want to create several plots where I zoom in part of the original plot. The labels of the regions outside the zoom area also appear.

This is a minimal example:

```
start = c(1, 5,8, 14, 19, 25)
end =c(3, 6,12, 16, 22, 30)
label = c(1,2,3, 4, 5, 6)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
regions = tibble::tibble(label, start, end)

ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
  geom_rect(
    data = regions,
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = start,
      xmax = end,
      ymin = 1.5,
      ymax = 1.8),
    color = "black",
    fill = "#56B4E9"
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = regions,
    aes(
       x = start + (end - start) / 2,
      y = 1.8,
      label = label,
    ),
    size = 10,
    force_pull   = 0,
    nudge_y      = 0.05,
    direction    = "x",
    angle        = 90,
    vjust        = 0,
    segment.size = 0.5,
  ) +
  ylim(1.38, 2.2) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_minimal()
```

This code generates this plot:

[image]

I want to zoom into box 3, so I tried adding `+ xlim(8,12)` or `+facet_zoom(xlim = c(8, 12))` but The zoomed plot has the annotation (labels) of box 1, box2, ... on the side as you can see here (1,2 in the right and 4,5,6 on the left of the zoomed plot)

[image]

and similar result with  `+ xlim(8,12)`

[image]

How can I remove the labels (annotation) outside the zoomed area (1,2 in the right and 4,5,6 on the left of the zoomed plot?)

Comment: For a quick fix you could simply subset your `regions` data in the `geom_text_repel()' call to only include label 3.

Comment: Thank you PLY, If I subset my `region` in `data` argument in `geom_text_repel`, the subset is a vector whereas `data` argument only takes a dataframe.

Comment: It would be great if I can do something like `data = (regions$label == 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two quick fixes I can think of, where the first is the one you already mentioned. Perhaps you mistyped it, as I can run it fine.

1. Set `xlim(8,12)`

```
library(ggrepel)
start = c(1, 5,8, 14, 19, 25)
end =c(3, 6,12, 16, 22, 30)
label = c(1,2,3, 4, 5, 6)

regions = data.frame(label, start, end)

ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
  geom_rect(
    data = regions,
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = start,
      xmax = end,
      ymin = 1.5,
      ymax = 1.8),
    color = "black",
    fill = "#56B4E9"
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = regions, 
    aes(
      x = start + (end - start) / 2,
      y = 1.8,
      label = label,
    ),
    size = 10,
    force_pull   = 0,
    nudge_y      = 0.05,
    direction    = "x",
    angle        = 90,
    vjust        = 0,
    segment.size = 0.5,
  ) +
  ylim(1.38, 2.2) +
  xlim(8, 12) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_minimal()
```

If I run this I obtain the following image [image]
However, using `xlim()` is not always advised as it throws away all the other points which do not meet the condition. Although for your case that might be favourable.

2. Subsetting `regions` and zooming in properly using `coord_cartesian()`.

```
ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
  geom_rect(
    data = regions,
    mapping = aes(
      xmin = start,
      xmax = end,
      ymin = 1.5,
      ymax = 1.8),
    color = "black",
    fill = "#56B4E9"
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = subset(regions, label == 3),
    aes(
      x = start + (end - start) / 2,
      y = 1.8,
      label = label,
    ),
    size = 10,
    force_pull   = 0,
    nudge_y      = 0.05,
    direction    = "x",
    angle        = 90,
    vjust        = 0,
    segment.size = 0.5,
  ) +
  ylim(1.38, 2.2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(8, 12)) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_minimal()
```

This produces the same image (as far as I can tell) [image]

Comment: Thank you so much PLY, I didn't know you can use `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(8, 12))` but I still got the same problem. I'm not sure why your plot is clean and doesn't include any of the labels of 1,2,4,5,6 on the side. I did copy the exact code you have here and paste it in a clean enviro in studio but I can't re-generate the same results as yours. My plot is still similar to the third plot in the original question.

Comment: @Sam, that's strange. As a side note, I slightly edited my code to `regions = data.frame(label, start, end)`. I'm not fully aware, but perhaps it could be due to your package versions or R version. Could you show your `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: it's working if I subset the regions data in `the geom_text_repel` call to only include label 3 using `data = subset(regions, regions$label == 3)`. Thank you so much PLY :)